# Nette phar boot file

Tags: php, phar, nette

I'm trying to create a single-file version of *PHP* framework *Nette 2.4*. I create a *phar* file using this code:

```
<?php
$phar = new Phar('nette.phar');
$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/nette');
$phar->setStub("<?php
    require 'phar://' . __FILE__ . '/loader.php';
    __HALT_COMPILER();");
$phar->compressFiles(Phar::GZ);
```

Everything is fine, the file is created. If I try to use this compacted version:

```
// bootstrap.php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/nette.phar';
...
```

Error occurs:

```
Warning: require(phar://C:\wamp64\www\app\nette.phar/loader.php): failed to open stream: phar error: &quot;loader.php&quot; is not a file in phar &quot;C:/wamp64/www/app/nette.phar&quot; in C:\wamp64\www\app\nette.phar on line 2
```

So, single-file version is loaded, but there is no boot file *loader.php*. Does anyone know where is the mistake? Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure there is loader.php? If you installed nette through composer it should be in `vendor/nette/nette/Nette/Framework.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create .phar from Nette downloaded via Composer. It doesn't have some necessary files (e.g. your Loader.php).

If you want to create .phar download official .zip from https://nette.org/en/download and create .phar from folder `./Nette`.

__

BTW you don't need to create .phar yourself, you can find it in the .zip file in folder `Nette-minified`